# Function substitution with an import

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm a Haskell newbie, and working with GHCi, version 7.6.3

I'm trying to understand why this function assignment (or substitution, whatever the correct term is) isn't working.

This code works fine:

```
import qualified Data.List as L
testSort list = L.sort list
```

Prompt:

```
*Main> testSort [3,2,1]
[1,2,3]
```

However, if I remove the list parameter like so...

```
import qualified Data.List as L
testSort = L.sort
```

To me, it makes intuitive sense that this would simple substitute L.sort for testSort, and then I could just run the same command at the prompt as before and get the same result.  However, I get a big error from GHCi:

```
No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of `L.sort'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
  testSort :: [a0] -> [a0] (bound at modulesandbox.hs:4:1)
Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
              or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Ord (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  instance Ord () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
  instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
  ...plus 23 others
In the expression: L.sort
In an equation for `testSort': testSort = L.sort
```

Is there a way to set up my code so that `testSort = L.sort` can behave as a simple function substitution?

Comment: Interesting. I can do `testSort = L.sort` just fine in GHCi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) strikes again.

Simply make it a habit to always write out type signatures, then this will never be a problem.

```
testSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: How does GHCi overcome this when I merely write `let testSort = L.sort` in the shell?

Comment: GHCi has recently made `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` the default.

Comment: Oh OK, wasn't aware of that. When I tried to compile it from a source file, I did get OP's error.!

Comment: @shree.pat18 Note that GHC suggested this fix: `Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature`

Comment: You might want to indicate how this is done in GHCi.

Comment: @dfeuer You can use `:set +m` for multiline input or you can use `let {testSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]; testSort = L.sort}`.

Comment: @bheklilr, *I* know how to do it; I suggested you add it to your answer for the benefit of those who may not.

Comment: @dfeuer Not my answer... I figured you know how to do it, I was just tagging your name on it so that future readers would know it's part of the same conversation.

Comment: @bheklilr: you don't need braces around such a "semicolon-typed" expression in GHCi. — Anyway, I don't quite see what that has to do with the question: in GHCi I usually don't write signatures. Definitions in GHCi needn't be readable (they'll be gone in the next session anyway) and `-XNoMono` makes sure this doesn't. When something in complex enough to need a signature, it's almost always better to define it in a proper file.